# Class cannot be instantiated on PHP 7.2

Tags: php, class, instance

It does instantiate on 5.6, however, I need to use 7.2 and the php that instantiate it stops where I have `$producto = new producto();` I can't access to error logs So I can't really check if there is something dumped about this. 
I have just tried to echo before and after this line and the echo after is not showing (as all the output after this line) so I guess the problem is the class itself.

```
<?php

class producto implements JsonSerializable
{
    private $precio;
    private $nombre;
    private $imagen;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPrecio()
    {
        return $this->precio;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $precio
     */
    public function setPrecio($precio)
    {
        $this->precio = $precio;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $nombre
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getImagen()
    {
        return $this->imagen;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $imagen
     */
    public function setImagen($imagen)
    {
        $this->imagen = $imagen;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $url
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }
    private $url;


    public function __construct($nombre,$precio,$imagen,$url)
    {
        $this->precio = $precio;
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->imagen = $imagen;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    { return[
        'nombre'=>$this->nombre,
        'precio'=>$this->precio,
        'imagen'=>$this->imagen,
        'url'=>$this->url,
    ];
    }
}
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: You need to pass parameters to the constructor - `$producto = new producto();` will not work with `public function __construct($nombre,$precio,$imagen,$url)`

Comment: @AbraCadaver I tried these codes but show nothing: I cannot access php-ini of server as it is a shared server to check the line that must be turned on for this to work.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/CYS0s

Comment: @NigelRen yes, this was the reason behind. But somehow that was working on 5.6! Strange isn't it? Well, I just put the constructor empty and it works again. Thanks a lot to help me see this evidence.

Comment: It was a warning before 7.1.0, now it's a fatal error. Check the link.